# Keycloak java script policy not visible after deploying as jar as per keycloak documentation

Tags: javascript, keycloak, abac

Keycloak java script policy not visible after deploying as jar as per keycloak documentation.

Steps :

1. Created a folder with META-INF folder and policy.js as below
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xZxf.png)
2. created jar and copied in the providers/ folder of keycloak home dir.
3. executed kc.bat build command - it shows success

and looking the policy in the clients policy dropdown but policy is not visible. Can you please help on it.
Thanks

Steps :

1. Created a folder with META-INF folder and policy.js as below
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xZxf.png)
2. created jar and copied in the providers/ folder of keycloak home dir.
3. executed kc.bat build command - it shows success

and looking the policy in the clients policy dropdown but policy is not visible. Can you please help on it.

Comment: keycloak version 22.0.4

Comment: I found the problem and the solution of it as well. Issue was scripts feature was not enabled so even after deploying the policy to keycloak, it was not visible in the keycloak admin ui. when enabled the scripts feature and redeployed policy. It was visible and could be used as needed. Thanks